# Why is the limit for POSIX message queues so low?

Tags: mqueue

Was going to use a bunch of message queues to communicate between different threads in two processes, but it appears that the max is 10 (Ubuntu 18.10).

Just wondering what the reason is for not having this default max number of message queues higher?

Comment: It might be historical, similar to the number of ports being limited to a  subset between 0 and 65535, and -1.